# XML Deserialization doesn't work with abstract class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize from a xml string to an object. But my obect is always null.

I have an abstract class (Response), a class that inherits from "Response" (DirectorSearchResponse), and an object in the class "DirectorSearchResponse" (HeaderResponse). This object is always null after deserialization.

Response.cs

```
public abstract class Response
{
    public HeaderResponse Header { get; set; }

    public Response()
    {
    }
}
```

DirectorSearchResponse.cs

```
[XmlRoot("xmlresponse")]
public class DirectorSearchResponse : Response
{
    public DirectorSearchResponse() : base()
    {
        /* DO NOTHING */
    }
}
```

HeaderResponse.cs

```
[XmlRoot("header")]
public class HeaderResponse
{
    [XmlElement("toto")]
    public String toto { get; set; }

    public HeaderResponse()
    {

    }
}
```

My running code :

```
        /* DESERIALIZE */
        String toto = "<xmlresponse><header><toto>tutu</toto><reportinformation><time>08/04/2016 13:33:37</time><reporttype> Error</reporttype><country>FR</country><version>1.0</version><provider>www.creditsafe.fr</provider><chargereference></chargereference></reportinformation></header><body><errors><errordetail><code>110</code><desc></desc></errordetail></errors></body></xmlresponse>";
        XmlSerializer xsOut = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DirectorSearchResponse));
        using (TextReader srr = new StringReader(toto))
        {
            DirectorSearchResponse titi = (DirectorSearchResponse)xsOut.Deserialize(srr);
        }
```

When I execute my code, the object "titi" is instanciate, but "Header" is always null.

How retrieve the "toto" value from xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is case sensitive, so you need to use [`[XmlElement("header")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.-ctor?#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute__ctor_System_String_) to inform the serializer of the correct element name for the `Header` property:

```
public abstract class Response
{
    [XmlElement("header")]
    public HeaderResponse Header { get; set; }

    public Response()
    {
    }
}
```

The [`[XmlRoot("header")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute) you have applied to `HeaderResponse` only controls its element name when it is the root element of an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the link to the abstract class like this :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response")]
public abstract class Response
{
     public HeaderResponse Header { get; set; }

    public Response()
    {
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response")]
public class DirectorSearchResponse : Response
{
    public DirectorSearchResponse() : base()
   {
    /* DO NOTHING */
   }
}
```

Comment: XmlRoot is to determine the root node of the xml right ?

Comment: [Xml root attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)