# ASP.NET Core API empty XML object

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, deserialization

I have a controller which contains POST method that have to receive an XML object and deserialize it. But after all my attempts I am always getting an empty object with all properties set to nulls or defaults.

Here is the code (sorry for this heap, but I think the mistake could be in any piece of the code.):

Order class:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement]
    public long OrderSource { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public long Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public decimal DiscountPercent { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string PayMethod { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public int QtyPerson { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public decimal ChangeAmount { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Remark { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string AddressRemark { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Phone Phone { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(nameof(Products))]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Customer class:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Address class:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Address
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string House { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Flat { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Floor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string DoorCode { get; set; }
}
```

And the Phone class:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Phone
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the body of the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
    <orderSource>0</orderSource>
    <type>0</type>
    <discountPercent>0</discountPercent>
    <payMethod>string</payMethod>
    <qtyPerson>0</qtyPerson>
    <changeAmount>0</changeAmount>
    <remark>string</remark>
    <customer>
        <name>asdasd</name>
    </customer>
    <address>
        <cityName>string</cityName>
        <streetName>string</streetName>
        <house>string</house>
        <flat>string</flat>
        <floor>string</floor>
        <doorCode>string</doorCode>
    </address>
    <addressRemark>string</addressRemark>
    <phone>
        <number>string</number>
    </phone>
    <products>
        <name>string</name>
        <code>string</code>
        <qty>0</qty>
        <price>0</price>
    </products>
</Order>
```

Tell me please, what should I change here, so the built-in deserializer could properly process the request? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem is that the **case** of your XML elements does not match the XML.  Your properties are pascal cased but the XML is camel cased.  And, unfortunately, XML is case-sensitive.  See: [Is XML case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7414747/3744182) (answer: yes) and [Case insensitive XML parser in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9334771/3744182).

Comment: You need to fix your property names or override them by setting setting [`XmlElementAttribute.ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.elementname) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36505504), e.g. `[XmlElement("orderSource")]`

Comment: @dbc Thanks! That worked for me! Would You mind posting an answer, so I would be able to mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the **case** of your XML elements does not match the XML.  Your properties are pascal cased but the XML is camel cased.  And, unfortunately, XML is case-sensitive.  See: [Is XML case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7414747/3744182) (answer: yes) and [Case insensitive XML parser in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9334771/3744182).

You need to fix your property names or override them by setting setting [`XmlElementAttribute.ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.elementname) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36505504) to *[XML Deserialization doesn't work with abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36503871/3744182)*, i.e.:

```cs
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement("orderSource")]
    public long OrderSource { get; set; }

    // And similarly for all remaining properties
```

Or

```cs
public class Order
{
    public long orderSource { get; set; }

    // And similarly for all remaining properties
```